# Force fragment recreate when activity configchanges screenSize and orientation

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment, android-lifecycle

I have activity with

```
        <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/name"
        android:configChanges="screenSize|orientation"
        android:launchMode="singleInstance">
```

but for one fragment I want it to act like activity configuration in manifest is without above configChanges.

Answer (score 0):

For `Fragments`, you should just use `setRetainInstance(true)` to prevent it from re-creating itself on a configuration change. However, keep in mind that you still need to recreate the *view* on configuration change. That is, `onDestroyView()` and `onCreateView()` will still be called, and any view references that you have should be released in `onDestroyView()` to avoid leaking the previous `Activity` instance.

Comment: But I want my fragment to recreate even if activity is not recreating because of configChanges attr in manifest

Comment: @ray20: did u get a way of doing this?